# Two step object creation in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to change the implementation of an EAV model using a JSONField to store all the attributes defined by an attribute_set.
I already figured out how to build a form to edit the single attributes of the JSON, but I'm currently stuck at implementing the creation of a new object. I think I have to split object creation in two steps, because I need to know the attribute_set to generate the correct form, but I don't know if there's a way to hook in the create action, or any other way to achieve what I need.

My models look like this:

```
class EavAttribute(models.Model):
    entity_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=entity_types)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=data_types)

class AttributeSet(models.Model):       
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField('EavAttribute')

class EntityAbstract(models.Model):          
    attribute_set = models.ForeignKey(
        'AttributeSet',
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        unique=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Event(EntityAbstract):                    
    entity_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, choices=entity_types, default=DEFAULT_ENTITY_TYPE)        
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)    
    year = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    begin_date = models.DateField()       
    end_date = models.DateField()
    data = JSONField()
```

How can I choose the AttributeSet first and then go to another form that I would populate with the attributes in the chosen attribute set?

Comment: If you post some code, with a specific error/problem you've encountered you'll find someone able to help you.

Comment: I haven't got any specific error, because I still have to figure out an approach to do what I need; my question is about getting guidance for implementing this. I updated my question including my models, just to clarify a bit how data is shaped.

Comment: From what I understand, you want to create a new `Event` model object, which depends on field `entity_type`'s `attribute_set` to get the attributes, which you will store in the field `data` of the `Event` model. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, @SachinKukreja, it's correct. I'm thinking on using the get_fields() method to display only attribute_set if the object does not already exist; with this approach I would save the object in the database having set only that attribute, which could be fine, but then i'd like to redirect the user to the form for editing the object, otherwise he would need to manually open it for edit.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using `get_fields()` and `response_add()` methods, like so:

```
def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj is None:
        return ['attribute_set']
    else:
        return [attr.name for attr in obj._meta.get_fields() if not attr.auto_created and attr.name != 'id']

def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    readonly_fields = ['entity_type', 'code', 'state']
    if obj is not None:
        readonly_fields.append('attribute_set')
    return readonly_fields

def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
    url = '/admin/risks/event/{}/change/'.format(obj.id)
    return redirect(url)
```

The downside of this approach is that object is saved in the database and then opened for edit, so basically the database is hit twice and all attributes have to be nullable, except for attribute_set.
I would be happy to receive ideas for better implementations.